# Custom Container Controller: transitionFromViewController: View not properly layed-out before animation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiappearance

This is both a question and a **partial** solution.

---

*Sample project here:

https://github.com/JosephLin/TransitionTest

---

### **Problem 1:**

When using `transitionFromViewController:...`, layouts done by the `toViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` doesn't show up when the transition animation begins. In other words, the pre-layout view shows during the animation, and it's contents snap to the post-layout positions after the animation.

### **Problem 2:**

If I customize the background of my navbar's `UIBarButtonItem`, the bar button shows up with the wrong size/position before the animation, and snaps to the correct size/position when the animation ends, similar to Problem 1.

---

To demonstrate the problem, I made a bare-bone custom container controller that does some custom view transitions. It's pretty much a UINavigationController copy that does cross-dissolve instead of push animation between views.

The 'Push' method looks like this:

```
- (void)pushController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];

    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];
    toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    NSLog(@"Before transitionFromViewController:");
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:0.5
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{}
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            }];
}
```

Now, `DetailViewController` (the view controller I'm pushing to) needs to layout its content in `viewWillAppear:`. It can't do it in `viewDidLoad` because it wouldn't have the correct frame at that time.

For demonstration purpose, `DetailViewController` sets its label to different locations and colors in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    CGRect rect = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
    rect.origin.y = 50;
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = rect;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = @"viewDidLoad";
    self.descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    CGRect rect = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
    rect.origin.y = 200;
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = rect;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = @"viewWillAppear";
    self.descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    CGRect rect = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
    rect.origin.y = 350;
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = rect;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = @"viewDidAppear";
    self.descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

---

Now, when pushing the `DetailViewController`, I'm expecting to see the label at `y =200` at the begining of the animation (left image), and then jumps to `y = 350` after the animation is finished (right image).

[image] [image]
**Expected view before and after animation.**

---

However, the label was at `y=50`, as if the layout made in `viewWillAppear` didn't make it before the animation took place (left image). But notice that the label's background was set to yellow (the color specified by `viewWillAppear`)!

[image] [image]
**Wrong layout at the beginning of the animation. Notice that the bar buttons also start with the wrong position/size.**

---

**Console Log**
TransitionTest[49795:c07] -[DetailViewController viewDidLoad]
TransitionTest[49795:c07] Before transitionFromViewController:
TransitionTest[49795:c07] -[DetailViewController viewWillAppear:]
TransitionTest[49795:c07] -[DetailViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
TransitionTest[49795:c07] -[DetailViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]
TransitionTest[49795:c07] -[DetailViewController viewDidAppear:]
**Notice that `viewWillAppear:` was called *AFTER* `transitionFromViewController:`**

---

### **Solution for Problem 1**

Alright, here comes the *partial* solution part. By explicitly calling `beginAppearanceTransition:` and `endAppearanceTransition` to `toViewController`, the view will have the correct layout before the transition animation takes place:

```
- (void)pushController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];

    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];
    toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [toViewController beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:NO];

    NSLog(@"Before transitionFromViewController:");
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:0.5
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{}
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                [toViewController endAppearanceTransition];
                            }];
}
```

**Notice that `viewWillAppear:` is now called BEFORE `transitionFromViewController:`**
TransitionTest[18398:c07] -[DetailViewController viewDidLoad]
TransitionTest[18398:c07] -[DetailViewController viewWillAppear:]
TransitionTest[18398:c07] Before transitionFromViewController:
TransitionTest[18398:c07] -[DetailViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
TransitionTest[18398:c07] -[DetailViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]
TransitionTest[18398:c07] -[DetailViewController viewDidAppear:]

---

### **But that doesn't fix Problem 2!**

For whatever reason, the navbar buttons still begin with the wrong position/size at the beginning of the transition animation. I spent so many time trying to find THE right solution but without luck. I'm starting to feel it's a bug in `transitionFromViewController:` or `UIAppearance` or whatever. Please, any insight you can offer to this question is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Other solutions I've tried**

- Call `[self.view addSubview:toViewController.view];` before `transitionFromViewController:`

It actually gives exactly the right result to the user, fixes both Problem 1&2. The problem is, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will both be called twice! It's problematic if I want to do some expansive animation or calculation in `viewDidAppear`.

- Call `[toViewController viewWillAppear:YES];` before `transitionFromViewController:`

I think it's pretty much the same as calling `beginAppearanceTransition:`. It fixes Problem 1 but not Problem 2. Plus, the doc says not to call `viewWillAppear` directly!

- Use `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` instead of `transitionFromViewController:`

Like this:
    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:toViewController.view];
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

It fixes Problem 2, but the view started with the layout in `viewDidAppear` (label is green, y=350). Also, the cross-dissolve is not as good as using `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`

Comment: Using `[self.view addSubview:toViewController.view]` actually seems a reasonable way to go (at least for my use case). Just put a check in those methods for whether they've already fired in the last second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, adding layoutIfNeeded to the toViewController.view seems to do the trick - this gets the view laid out properly before it shows up on screen (without the add/remove), and no more weird double viewDidAppear: call.

```
- (void)pushController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];

    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];

    toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [toViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    NSLog(@"Before transitionFromViewController:");
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:0.5
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{}
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            }];

}
```

Comment: Hi escrafford, thanks for the answer. It fixes part of the problem but still isn't a prefect solution. The bar button is still acting weird (problem 2), plus the `viewWillAppear:` is being called twice, which might be problematic in some cases. Also, I'm getting a 'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions' warning.

Comment: did my modifications fix the problem?

Comment: Hm...you might be on the right track. The **Right bar button** no longer distorts, but the **Left bar button**, and the buttons on the bottom tool bar still do.

Comment: Joseph Lin .. Got any clue? Weirdly I too am seeing this problem only with leftBarButtonItems and not with the title.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, all you need is forwarding appearance transactions and UIView.Animate. This approach fixes all problems, doesn't create new ones. Here is some C# code (xamarin):

```
var fromView = fromViewController.View;
var toView = toViewController.View;

fromViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(null);
AddChildViewController(toViewController);

fromViewController.BeginAppearanceTransition(false, true);
toViewController.BeginAppearanceTransition(true, true);

var frame = fromView.Frame;
frame.X = -viewWidth * direction;
toView.Frame = frame;
View.Add(toView);

UIView.Animate(0.3f,
    animation: () =>
    { 
        toView.Frame = fromView.Frame; 
        fromView.MoveTo(x: viewWidth * direction);
    },
    completion: () =>
    {
        fromView.RemoveFromSuperview();

        fromViewController.EndAppearanceTransition();
        toViewController.EndAppearanceTransition();

        fromViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
        toViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
    }
);
```

and of course you should disable automatic forwarding of appearance methods and do it manually:

```
public override bool ShouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods
{
    get { return false; }
}

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    CurrentViewController.BeginAppearanceTransition(true, animated);
}

public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    CurrentViewController.EndAppearanceTransition();
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    CurrentViewController.BeginAppearanceTransition(false, animated);
}

public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
    CurrentViewController.EndAppearanceTransition();
}
```