# Custom ViewController Transitions: Get ToViewController's Subview's Frame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, transition, custom-transition

Here's an illustration of my question:

[image: Illustration]

I have *StarImageView*s in ViewControllers A & B that displays the same image but have different frames from each other in its ViewController.

When *StarImageView* in ViewController A is tapped, the app pushes a new view controller into the navigation controller stack and at the same time, animates to its final frame in ViewController B.

**This behaviour is just like the transition in the iPhone Photos app.**

---

## How I'm doing it now

I initialise a temp UIImageView in the animator object with the initial *StarImageView's* frame and image in ViewController A, and animate it to a final frame by hard-coding the rect `CGRectMake(0, 60+44, containerView.bounds.size.width, containerView.bounds.size.width)` (frame of *StarImageView* in ViewController B), and removing the temp UIImageView from superview in the animation completion block.

---

## How I wish to do it instead

The project is created in storyboard with autolayout enabled. What I wish to do is to get the frame of *StarImageView* in ViewController B during the transition rather than hard-coding it like above. Due to the ViewContorller lifecycle, I am unable to reference any subviews in ViewController B in the animator object as they haven't been initialised yet.

Are there any other solutions or best practices for such situations? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25506785/2853872), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28532622/2853872), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14713030/2853872) but no luck in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[toViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];